# "Missing argument parameter 'queue' in call"

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

I'm trying to use `SKAction.repeatActionForever` to run a sequence consisting of an `SKAction` and a random delay between repeats.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let sequence = [
            SKAction.runBlock(spawnObstacle), //Missing argument for parameter 'queue' in call
            SKAction.waitForDuration(self.random(min: player.speed, max: player.speed * 2 as CGFloat))
    ]

    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence(sequence)))

}
func random() -> CGFloat{
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}



func random(#min:CGFloat, max:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() * (max - min) + min
}
```

`spawnObstacle` is a function with no parameters that returns void, and `player.speed` is a `CGFloat`.

I'm getting the error `Missing argument for parameter 'queue' in call` on `SKAction.runBlock(spawnObstacle)`. I think this has something to do with types, and that for some reason runBlock doesn't like `spawnObstacle()`, and is trying to call

```
func runBlock(_ block: dispatch_block_t,queue queue: dispatch_queue_t?) -> SKAction
```

instead of

```
func runBlock(_ block: dispatch_block_t) -> SKAction
```

I tried call `SKAction.runBlock(spawnObstacle as dispatch_block_t)` to see what would happen, and it got rid of the error, only to bring up another one:

```
SKAction.waitForDuration(self.random(min: player.speed, max: player.speed * 2 as CGFloat)) //Extra argument 'min' in call
```

I think this one is similar to the other one (which I'm not sure I actually solved, other than faking out the compiler). It seems like the compiler thinks that player.speed is not a CGFloat so it goes to `random()` instead of `random(#min:CGFloat, max:CGFloat)`.

My question is: Why are these two errors occurring when the types are, as far as I can tell, correct?

EDIT: Here is `spawnObstacle()`

```
func spawnObstacle() -> Void{

    let obst = Obstacle(
        color: UIColor.redColor(),
        size: CGSize(width: 50.0,height: 50.0))

    let node = SKSpriteNode(color: obst.color, size: obst.size)

    node.position = CGPoint(x: size.width, y: 0 + obst.size.height / 2)

    addChild(node)

    let duration = player.speed

    let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x:0 - obst.size.width / 2,y:node.position.y), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration))
    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    node.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove,actionMoveDone]))
}
```

Comment: how is spawnObstacle declared and implemented?

Comment: Ok, I added spawnObstacle()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift sometimes emits errors that don't have anything to do with the real problem. In this case your problem is that `SKAction.waitForDuration` expects an NSTimeInterval but you are passing in a CGFloat. You need to construct an NSTimeInterval from the CGFloat.

```
let sequence = [
    SKAction.runBlock(spawnObstacle),
    SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(random(min: player.speed, max: player.speed * 2)))
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get so many nonsense debugger errors and couldn't find anything wrong with what the debugger found. I never thought that there actually were errors, but different from those shown! Thank god for the newer versions with those bugs fixed (currently coding on an older version of xcode)!